# how to print data in new line after " | " in String

Tags: java, android

```
map.put("RowID", String.valueOf(RowID));
map.put(KEY_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_NAME));
```

After parsing I'm getting data

```
13/2012 | Section 10(15), item (h) of sub-clause (iv) of the Income-tax Act, 1961 - Exemptions - Interest on bonds/debentures - Notified bonds/debentures of Public Sector Companies - Corrigendum to notification no.7/2012, dated 14-2-2012
```

I want to separate after `|` and print data like that

```
13/2012 Section
10(15), item (h) of sub-clause (iv) of the Income-tax Act, 1961 - Exemptions - Interest on bonds/debentures - Notified bonds/debentures of Public Sector Companies - Corrigendum to notification no.7/2012, dated 14-2-2012
```

How can I do this?

Comment: separation with | will not print as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) method:

```
String finalString = oldString.replace("|", "\n");
```

Or use [`String#split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29):

```
String[] splitted = oldString.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
```

Comment: shouldn't it be replace("|", "\n")?

Comment: i have to remove also | from string ?

Answer (score 2):

Use the String.replace().

For example:

```
    String s = "hello | world";

    System.out.println(s.replace("|", "\n"));
```

This prints out:

hello 
 world

Answer (score 1):

To be platform independent (which is not strictly needed as you are working on android)

```
System.out.println(yourString.replaceAll("\\|", System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

This will replace all | as well in case your string has multiple |